# Reading a table from a file only results in the first record being stored

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

Additional background: this is a follow-up to [Adding two integers giving unwanted result in cobol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63988919/adding-two-integers-giving-unwanted-result-in-cobol).

As the input data consists of strings and integers are needed for calculating, this program bulk reads each row, then read each field individually from the file and convert the necessary fields to numbers when storing them in the working storage section table.

Now, for some reason, only the first record reads and stores properly. The rest of the records are being read as blanks or nulls, I guess, even though the file contents after the first record are obviously not null.

Here is my current code for the full program:

```
    IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
    PROGRAM-ID. GRADEREPORT.
    AUTHOR. JORDAN RENAUD.
    DATE-WRITTEN. 09/18/2020.
    
    ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
    INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
    FILE-CONTROL.
           SELECT GRADES-FILE ASSIGN TO "bill"
               ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL
               ACCESS IS SEQUENTIAL.
    
    DATA DIVISION.
    FILE SECTION.
    FD GRADES-FILE.
    01     INPUT-TOTAL-POINTS       PIC 9(4).
    01     INPUT-GRADES.
    05         INPUT-GRADE OCCURS 1 to 100 TIMES DEPENDING ON RECORD-COUNT.
    10            INPUT-ASSIGNMENT-NAME   PIC X(20).
    10            INPUT-CATEGORY          PIC X(20).
    10            INPUT-POINTS-POSSIBLE   PIC X(14).
    10            INPUT-POINTS-EARNED     PIC X(14).
    
    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    77     GRADES-FILE-EOF          PIC 9.
    01     RECORD-COUNT             PIC 9(8) VALUE 0.
    01     TOTAL-EARNED-POINTS      PIC 9(14) VALUE ZERO.
    01     TOTAL-POSSIBLE-POINTS    PIC 9(14) VALUE 5.
    01     K                        PIC 9(14) VALUE 1.
    01     TMP                      PIC 9(14).
    01     CURRENT-CATEGORY         PIC X(20).
    01     CATEGORY-WEIGHT          PIC X(3).
    01     LAST-CATEGORY            PIC X(20).
    01     TOTAL-POINTS             PIC 9(4).
    01     GRADES.
    05         GRADE OCCURS 1 TO 100 TIMES DEPENDING ON RECORD-COUNT.
    10            ASSIGNMENT-NAME   PIC X(20).
    10            CATEGORY          PIC X(20).
    10            POINTS-POSSIBLE   PIC 9(14).
    10            POINTS-EARNED     PIC 9(14).
    
    PROCEDURE DIVISION.
           OPEN INPUT GRADES-FILE.
           READ GRADES-FILE INTO TOTAL-POINTS.
           DISPLAY TOTAL-EARNED-POINTS
           PERFORM UNTIL GRADES-FILE-EOF = 1
               READ GRADES-FILE
                  AT END SET
                  GRADES-FILE-EOF TO 1
                  NOT AT END
                     ADD 1 TO RECORD-COUNT
    
                     MOVE INPUT-ASSIGNMENT-NAME(RECORD-COUNT) TO ASSIGNMENT-NAME(RECORD-COUNT)
                     DISPLAY INPUT-ASSIGNMENT-NAME(RECORD-COUNT)
                     DISPLAY ASSIGNMENT-NAME(RECORD-COUNT)
    
                     MOVE INPUT-CATEGORY(RECORD-COUNT) TO CATEGORY(RECORD-COUNT)
                     DISPLAY INPUT-CATEGORY(RECORD-COUNT)
                     DISPLAY CATEGORY(RECORD-COUNT)
    
                     MOVE FUNCTION NUMVAL (INPUT-POINTS-POSSIBLE(RECORD-COUNT)) TO POINTS-POSSIBLE(RECORD-COUNT)
                     DISPLAY INPUT-POINTS-POSSIBLE(RECORD-COUNT)
                     DISPLAY POINTS-POSSIBLE(RECORD-COUNT)
    
                     MOVE FUNCTION NUMVAL (INPUT-POINTS-EARNED(RECORD-COUNT)) TO POINTS-EARNED(RECORD-COUNT)
                     DISPLAY INPUT-POINTS-EARNED(RECORD-COUNT)
                     DISPLAY POINTS-EARNED(RECORD-COUNT)
    
                     COMPUTE TOTAL-EARNED-POINTS = TOTAL-EARNED-POINTS + POINTS-EARNED(RECORD-COUNT)
                     DISPLAY TOTAL-EARNED-POINTS
               END-READ
           END-PERFORM.
           CLOSE GRADES-FILE.
           DISPLAY TOTAL-EARNED-POINTS.
           SORT GRADE ASCENDING CATEGORY.
           MOVE CATEGORY(1) TO LAST-CATEGORY.
           PERFORM RECORD-COUNT TIMES
               MOVE CATEGORY(K) TO CURRENT-CATEGORY
               IF CURRENT-CATEGORY = LAST-CATEGORY THEN
                  DISPLAY "SAME CATEGORY"
               ELSE
                  DISPLAY "NEW CATEGORY"
                  MOVE LAST-CATEGORY TO CURRENT-CATEGORY
               END-IF
               SET K UP BY 1
           END-PERFORM
           DISPLAY GRADES.
           STOP RUN.
```

and here is the input file, bill:

```
1000
MS 1 - Join Grps    Group Project       5             5             
Four Programs       Programming         15            9             
Quiz 1              Quizzes             10            7             
FORTRAN             Programming         25            18            
Quiz 2              Quizzes             10            9             
HW 1 - Looplang     Homework            20            15
```

As per the code written, the first line read from the table section of the file(lines 2 and forward) has its individual parts DISPLAY 'ed as follows:

```
MS 1 - Join Grps    
MS 1 - Join Grps    
Group Project       
Group Project       
5             
00000000000005
5             
00000000000005
```

This is what I expect. Each item is repeated, the first iteration is the input file structure, and the second is the working storage section structure. The difference being that the input structures are read as all strings of 20 and 14 lengths, and the storage structures are formatted as two strings of 20 length, and two ints of 14 length. The numeric strings are converted to ints and stored in the working storage, as stated earlier.
The output of the second row's DISPLAYs show as this:

```
00000000000000
              
00000000000000
00000000000005
                    
                    
                    
                    
              
00000000000000
              
00000000000000
00000000000005
                    
                    
                    
                    
              
00000000000000
              
00000000000000
00000000000005
                    
                    
                    
                    
              
00000000000000
              
00000000000000
00000000000005
                    
                    
                    
                    
              
00000000000000
              
00000000000000
00000000000005
```

In this case, the `00000000000005` is the total of a summation accumulator variable, which is always 5 because the first row reads 5 for the earned points, and the rest of them are just evaluating to zero because they're being read as blanks.

How can I get my program to properly read the rest of the file?

Comment: Out of interest: `-debug` raises no exception?
From a quick glance it looks like you likely want to drop the ODO (`OCCURS DEPENDIG ON`) from the input file.
And you may want to use `EXIT PERFORM` instead of setting and then checking an eof-variable and/or split the code into `SECTION`s (or pre-cobol85-style paragraphs-only) to increase readability (but that's more a style question, so just a note).
If you get it working yourself please self-answer (Q&A-stye), otherwise please drop a note after edit.

Comment: Note: I've edited your question to follow SO rules, please have a look at the edit.
We can chat via comments are also "cleaned" automatically, with the exception of up-voted comments [these are intended for "gives insight to the question/answer"] or also via discussion boards. another note: it is good to have posted it as additional question and your questions show research so they're a perfect match here.

Comment: I appreciate your insight and edits, these are things I could do, but my only real goal is to have a *working* program that takes the defined input, and returns a defined output report. Basically, in this Programming Languages class, we're given groups, and an assignment called "Four programs". First, we can implement them in whatever language we want. Then we had to do it in Fortran 66 (IV), and now it's Cobol. So it's less of knowing the algorithms required to get the output needed, and more of figuring out how to implement the same algs in different languages, and observe how the language

Comment: (2) you're writing the program in can simplify the process.

Comment: Oh, and to answer your question, adding the -debug flag to my launch.json hasn't really made a difference in console output. I'm using the debugger (first time using one really) to step through but It's still not helpful in finding out why it's not reading the whole thing like I want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, when reading a table from a file, the subscript to access the current line is always 1, so instead of reading RECORD-COUNT as the subscript of the INPUT-items, I just put 1 for all of them, and the program works as expected!

Comment: The file has only an "optical" table. Keep in mind that the `READ` will read a single line and place it into the record you tell it to. Each of those records are one entry of the optical table, so you'd likely drop the `OCCURS` altogether.
For a nice Q&A in SO I suggest to edit your answer with an updated code (part) together with your explanation and "accept" your answer as "works for me".

Comment: Yeah, I had to wait 21 hours to accept my own answer, I'm still waiting but will edit later when I'm not at work.